# Saving multiple rows of gridview into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which populated via selected item on my drop down list, I don't have any problem with that. My problem is I am trying to save multiple rows on my gridview into my database, for example I have added 3 items on my gridview which looks like this:

```
Id  | Name
111 | Jack
222 | Nicole
333 | John
```

Now, I want all that under column Id which is 111, 222 and 333 will be save on my database once I click Save button I am trying the code below but it gives me an error saying "system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter does not contain a definition for 'Values' and no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type..." :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("Insert into profile (Id, profile_id)VALUES(@id, @profile_id", con);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {

        cmdd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Char, 20, "Id").Values = row.Cells["Id"].Value;
    }

    cmdd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_id", txtID.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My table should be look like this once I am able to save multiple rows from my gridview into my database:

```
auto_id | Id | profile_id
1       |111 | 101
2       |222 | 101
3       |333 | 101
```

What am I missing? I'm using asp.net with C#.

Answer (score 1):

The error which you are getting because of, you are using `Values` but actually it's `Value`. So try this

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   cmdd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Char, 20, "Id").Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I have tried your code but it gives me an error at row.Cells["Id"]. It says "the best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments". Thanks again

Comment: @user2388316 ok, So you need to pass the index of the column `Id` instead of name "id". I have updated my answer.I am assuming that `Id` is the first column that's why I have used `Cells[0]`.